# Python script: Retrieve multiple results from Maps query

Tags: python

I am working on creating a python script which allows me to query Google Maps for a location. The thing is that my query will give me a list of results instead of  a single location (example query: Restaurants in New Delhi) and I want to save the whole list. The code to retrieve one location that I have tried so far is as follows:

```
import requests
import ast

def google_maps(req): 

    req.replace(' ','+')
    uri = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/'
    url = uri+req
    ret = requests.get(url).text
    scrape = '['+ret.split('cacheResponse([[')[1].split(',[')[0].split(',',1)[1]
    location = ast.literal_eval(scrape)
    print(location)



 google_maps('Restaurants in New Delhi')
```

How do I extend this code so that I can get the whole list of results sent by Maps?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bunch of `split`s to isolate one location.  Instead, `literal_eval` the whole of `ret` so you can extract each of the locations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Scott. I tried passing ret to literal_eval and it doesn't work. It shows an error in ast.py in the literal_eval function saying its an invalid syntax. Should I post the error here?

Comment: The error is as follows:

File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

Comment: To get rid of the error I tried the following and I am not getting the error now. literal_eval wasn't able to read some of the info so I encoded it to utf-8 and now it can. What i did is the following
location = ast.literal_eval(ret.encode('utf-8').strip())....Now 
it returns the whole HTML page to me when I print location. I don't know how to get the locations I need from the HTML page returned

Comment: Can you show the portion of text that you want parsed into a list?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Scott. I implemented the same thing using Google Places API. I got it done.